# new to spring, not able to delete user using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, java-ee-6

I am new to spring, was working on an example. The example shows how to add data to table using hibernate and list it also, I tried to add extra delete option but its updating record instead. I will post complete code below. ( 2 ) I develop simple web apps using jsp and servlets and lots of jquery ajax, I want to use ajax also with spring, will I be able to code the same way or its something different which i have to learn. To be frank I am scared after seeing the spring pattern.. :).

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/production"/>
        <property name="username" value="tpsl_admin"/>
        <property name="password" value="admin"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.org.domain.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myUserDAO" class="com.org.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/user/*.htm" class="com.org.web.UserController" >
        <property name="userDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
    </bean>

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

UserDAO.java

```
package com.org.dao;
import com.org.domain.User;
import java.util.List;

public interface UserDAO {

    public void saveUser(User user) ;
    public List<User> listUser() ;
        public void deleteUser(User user) ;
}
```

UserDAOImpl.java

```
package com.org.dao;
import com.org.domain.User;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> listUser() {
        return hibernateTemplate.find("from User");
    }

        @Override
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        hibernateTemplate.delete(user);
    }
}
```

User.java

```
package com.org.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String gender;
    private String country;
    private String aboutYou;
    private String[] community;
    private Boolean mailingList;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_PASSWORD")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_GENDER")
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_COUNTRY")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_ABOUT_YOU")
    public String getAboutYou() {
        return aboutYou;
    }
    public void setAboutYou(String aboutYou) {
        this.aboutYou = aboutYou;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_COMMUNITY")
    public String[] getCommunity() {
        return community;
    }
    public void setCommunity(String[] community) {
        this.community = community;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_MAILING_LIST")
    public Boolean getMailingList() {
        return mailingList;
    }
    public void setMailingList(Boolean mailingList) {
        this.mailingList = mailingList;
    }

}
```

UserController.java

```
package com.org.web;
import com.org.dao.UserDAO;
import com.org.domain.User;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;

public class UserController extends MultiActionController {

    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }
        @RequestMapping(params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, User user) throws Exception {
        userDAO.saveUser(user);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }
        @RequestMapping(params = "delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @Transactional
        public ModelAndView delete(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, User user) throws Exception {
        userDAO.deleteUser(user);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }

    public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
        modelMap.addAttribute("userList", userDAO.listUser());
        modelMap.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return new ModelAndView("userForm", modelMap);
    }
}
```

ok thats all with the code, the ide i am using is netbeans, sprinf ver is 3.1.1. Hibernate 3.0. Some one please show me where i need to change I am trying since 2 days with fail. Also explain my own code if possible I have many doubts.

Thankyou

userForm.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
.even {
    background-color: silver;
}
</style>
<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form:form action="add.htm" commandName="user" method="post">
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>User Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gender :</td>
            <td><form:radiobutton path="gender" value="M" label="M" /> 
                            <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="F" label="F" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country :</td>
            <td><form:select path="country">
                <form:option value="0" label="Select" />
                <form:option value="India" label="India" />
                <form:option value="USA" label="USA" />
                <form:option value="UK" label="UK" />
            </form:select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>About you :</td>
            <td><form:textarea path="aboutYou" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Community :</td>
            <td><form:checkbox path="community" value="Spring" label="Spring" /> 
                            <form:checkbox path="community" value="Hibernate" label="Hibernate" />
                            <form:checkbox path="community" value="Struts" label="Struts" />
                        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><form:checkbox path="mailingList" label="Would you like to join our mailinglist?" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="add" value="Register"></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<c:if test="${fn:length(userList) > 0}">
    <table cellpadding="5">
        <tr class="even">
                        <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>About You</th>
                        <th>Mailing List</th>
                        <th>Community</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user" varStatus="status">
            <tr class="<c:if test="${status.count % 2 == 0}">even</c:if>">
                                <td>${user.id}</td>
                <td>${user.name}</td>
                <td>${user.gender}</td>
                <td>${user.country}</td>
                <td>${user.aboutYou}</td>
                                <td>${user.mailingList}</td>
                                <td>${user.community}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: show the **error** and the `userForm.jsp`, maybe your url mapping wrong

Comment: add your print stake  trace so get error type and line number

Comment: It could be worthwhile checking out Matt Raible's [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) or at the very least the associated [demos and videos](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Demos+and+Videos) to get an idea of how things hang together and how the different frameworks available can help you in constructing an application.

Comment: I did not get any error, just the delete is updating instead of deleting user and when i restart(close and open) the app, the data is lost from db also. I will attach the userForm.jsp in the above question itself. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

In your dispatcherservlet.xml please comment the below line

```
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

as everytime when you restart your server, it will auto create the table when server starts.  Please check the mapping correctly for deleting the user and have print or breakpoints and debug the issue, seeing your code **hibernateTemplate.delete(user)** should work fine.